# How to handle SSL connection error with vertx WebClient

Tags: java

I try to use WebClient to send a HTTPS request,  Here is my code:

```
public T get(int port, String host, String api) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    WebClientOptions webClientOptions = new WebClientOptions();
    webClientOptions.setSsl(true).setVerifyHost(true).setTrustAll(true);
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, webClientOptions);
    CompletableFuture<T> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    webClient.get(port, host, api).ssl(true).as(BodyCodec.json(entityClass)).send(ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            T result = ar.result().body();
            completableFuture.complete(result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Info: " + ar.cause());
        }
    });

    return completableFuture.get();
}
```

The dependency I use is vertx-web-client 3.5.0
While running this project,I get an error:

```
 Error Info: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to create SSL connection
    10:30:36.919 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] WARN  i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
    io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:281)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1215)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1127)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1162)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

I look up some infomation, but still can't resolve it, Can you help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Uhm I really don't think this is your code...

Comment: It has been modified，Thanks

Comment: Did you import the SSL certificate to your jdk/ jre ???

Comment: @Agam yes,I have imported

Comment: use JksOptions(specify truststore) or PemTrustOptions(specify domain certificate) and set in webclientoptions. It will work. Disable setVerifyHost(true).setTrustAll(true) in prod / staging

Answer (score 7):

I solved my issue, setting the verifyHost to false -> setVerifyHost(false).

Comment: Use this if the ssl certificate is self generated ( not trusted)